# Why is there unintended huge space between rows in my Table, in MS Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

The entitled question above is depicted in my screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the following at the bottom left corner of the screenshot that you posted:

[image: img]

As you can see, the length of the *top margin* is between *13 to 14 units,* and thus you see the extra space. Hover the mouse over that and drag it upwards to your desired position.